# How to avoid Recovery Catalog's metadata being purged after 60 days?

Tags: oracle, backup, rman

I'm using Oracle's Recovery Catalog to track my db's backups metadata (RC ver. is 12.01.00.02 )

I need to collect historical backup sizes but then I've realized there's no metadata information about completed backups beyond 60 days. (however, there's for FAILED and incompleted backups)

e.g. I'm trying to collect this data from `rc_rman_backup_job_details` view. This RC's was used since Q1 2015, but only 60 days of completed backups are shown.

```
RMAN@SERESCATALOG> SELECT status, MIN(start_time)
      2  FROM rc_rman_backup_job_details
      3  GROUP BY status
      4  ORDER by status;

STATUS      MIN(START_TIME)
----------- --------------------
COMPLETED   03-SEP-2016 01:31:34
FAILED      18-SEP-2015 09:03:50
RUNNING     28-MAY-2015 02:39:36
```

What controls this retention? There's any way to change it? Any documentation?

Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is described in the note:

[How to Clean up The information in EM Backup Report (Doc ID 430601.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=430601.1)

Edit `recover.bsq`, find the procedure `cleanupRSR`, change the default value 60 as needed:

```
  DELETE FROM rsr
        WHERE rsr_end < nowTime-60
          AND rsr.dbinc_key IN
              (select dbinc_key from dbinc
               where dbinc.db_key = this_db_key);
```

When finished:

```
RMAN> upgrade catalog;
```

Comment: Why would you delete from the rsr table? Just because you can delete records from rsr, doesn't mean that you should. If the OP changes the two parameters, then the catalog will maintain itself, provided that he does a crosscheck backup and archivelog.

Comment: @Gandolf989 I did not suggest a manual deletion, records are deleted automatically by the database by using this script. What you wrote about is unrelated to this problem.

Comment: @Gandolf989 backup retention is irrelevant here. In fact, my backup retention is 15 days max, and having more is just unreliable (DBs > 5TB) and out of scope.
BalazsPapp , wow, that was accurate. I'll give it a shot in an test environment.  But when this procedures are called?

Comment: There are two things to think about. The backup retention is the number of backups that you keep on on disk. for you that would be 15 days. However, the number of days of backups that you keep in the RMAN catalog is controlled by the recovery window and the number of days that the backup information is kept in the control file is controlled by the control_file_record_keep_time. Hence, my answer was correct.

Comment: @Gandolf989 absolutely wrong. Retention Policy parameter is set to configure the backup retention, which can be set in terms of backup redundancy or a recovery window policy (please check https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/backup.111/b28270/glossary.htm#i432137 ). You're right about the control_file_record_keep_time parameter, but is not relevant here because,.. well,. that's why I'm using a RC. I want my backup records on a RC, not in a HUGE controlfile (big mistake here, btw)... besides, if I recall correctly, backup records are deleted from controlfile once backups are deleted.

Comment: @BalazsPapp I tested with a RC ver 12.1.0.2 and it changes a little bit as the Doc states ( in the cleanupROUT Procedure ) but it works perfectly. Thanks! . BTW, in 12.1.0.2, ignore the note in recover.bsq about editing recover.txt.

Answer (score -1):

Connect to your database using RMAN and try the following command.
Where 90 is the number of days that you want to keep backup data 
in your RMAN catalog.

```
CONFIGURE RETENTION POLICY TO RECOVERY WINDOW OF 90 DAYS;
```

Also under sqlplus you can set the number of days for the control 
files to track the backup information for RMAN.

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET control_file_record_keep_time=90;
```

Comment: If you change the recovery window than the backups are kept for 90 days. That's not what the OP wants. He only want to  keep that backup information. (e.g. backup sizes)